# angular data binding with lazy loaded controllers

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load my controllers in angular via requirejs

```
.when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                resolve: {
                    load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        // At this point, use whatever mechanism you want
                        // in order to lazy load dependencies. e.g. require.js
                        // In this case, "itemsController" won't be loaded
                        // until the user hits the '/items' route
                        require(['controllers/main'], function () {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                deferred.resolve();
                            });
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }]
                }
            });
```

This is my controller

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('someApp.controllers.MainCtrl', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.abc = "abc";
return app;
});
```

My view doesnt show the variable abc. Even though the view is rendering fine

```
<span>abc={{abc}}</span>
```

Comment: Is there `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` anywhere?

Comment: No this is what I have *<div ng-view></div>*

Comment: I am not sure if I can use ng-controller because I am lazy loading?

Comment: You always have to use it in the html to know where you apply it